# Product Prices Not Showing On Category Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, price, category-view

I can't seem to find anyone else that has had this problem. But I noticed my category pages are not showing the product prices.  `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` works on any custom templates I've created but not on the category pages. Must be a setting I'm overlooking?

How come `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` isn't working on the category pages?

Comment: please paste here your category page code.

Comment: What kind of product are you using?

Comment: I found the problem. It was a TrustSpot review module. Now just trying to fix it.  Thanks